# in Oracle database, how do I create a table of varchar2 type without length

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

for using it as a returning type in a function, I need to create a type at database level.
I do it by typing the command :

```
CREATE TYPE empno_tbl 
    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

but  this obliges me to choose a length.
I would like to create a string kind table type without a specific length.

is there a way to do this ?

Comment: The maximum length for `VARCHAR2()` is 4000, so you can just use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want it without a length then use `CLOB`.

```sql
CREATE TYPE empno_tbl IS TABLE OF CLOB;
```

*(There is a limit but in Oracle 19c [the `CLOB` datatype has a limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/datatype-limits.html#GUID-963C79C9-9303-49FE-8F2D-C8AAF04D3095) of 4GB * `DB_BLOCK_SIZE` initialization parameter, which gives a total size of 8 TB to 128 TB, and if you are reaching that limit then there is probably something wrong with your approach.)*

The maximum size for a `VARCHAR2` is 4000 bytes, so if you can cope with that limit then just use:

```sql
CREATE TYPE empno_tbl IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```